# Python numpy/matplotlib Axis/function Scaling

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, complexity-theory

I'm a matplotlib & numpy noob, but I'm trying to easily graph/visualize the asymptotic runtime of functions. The below snippet graphs some lines to compare to and a function that is asymptotically O(n^2), yet the graph does not make it obvious that it is an O(n^2) function. I've toyed around with the scaling of the axes, but couldn't improve the result. Is there a way to make the asymptotic runtime obvious at a glance aside from re-scaling the inputs by 10?

```
def foo(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    time.sleep(n ** 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = np.array([])
    times = np.array([])
    for i in range(10):
        inputs = np.append(inputs, [i])
        times = np.append(times, timeit("foo({})".format(i / 10), "from __main__ import foo", number=1))

    pyplot.plot(lin := [i for i in range(10)], lin, label="linear", marker='x')
    pyplot.plot([i for i in range(10)], [i**2 for i in range(10)], label="n**2", marker='.')
    pyplot.plot(inputs, times, label="foo", marker='x')
    pyplot.grid(True)
    pyplot.xlabel("x")
    pyplot.ylabel("y")
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.title("Graph")
    pyplot.show()
```

Resultant graph
[image]

Update: A twin axis approach gets me a little closer to what I'm looking for. Maybe there's a way to improve it further?

```
def foo(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    time.sleep(n ** 2)

def linfoo(n):
    time.sleep(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = np.array([])
    foo_times = np.array([])
    linfoo_times = np.array([])
    for i in range(10):
        inputs = np.append(inputs, [i])
        foo_times = np.append(foo_times, timeit("foo({})".format(i / 10), "from __main__ import foo", number=1))
        linfoo_times = np.append(linfoo_times, timeit("linfoo({})".format(i / 10), "from __main__ import linfoo", number=1))

    figure, ax1 = pyplot.subplots()
    ax1.set_xlabel("Input (n)")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Reference")
    ax1.plot([i for i in range(10)], [i**2 for i in range(10)], label="n**2", marker='.')
    ax1.plot(lin := [i for i in range(10)], lin, label="linear", marker='x')
    ax1.legend()

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.set_ylabel("Runtime")
    ax2.plot(inputs, foo_times, label="foo", marker='x', color='tab:green')
    ax2.plot(inputs, linfoo_times, label="linfoo", marker='x', color='tab:purple')
    ax2.legend(loc=1)

    figure.tight_layout()
    pyplot.grid(True)
    pyplot.xlabel("x")
    pyplot.ylabel("y")
    pyplot.title("Graph")
    pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: matplotlib will automatically rescale. Just don't plot your "linear" and "n**2" functions. If this is not obvious enough then you probably want to fit your data.

Comment: I'm confused by the "re-scaling the inputs by 10". Why would that make it more obvious? Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcZTq.png) what you're looking for?

Comment: Rescaling the inputs by 10 would make the n**2 and foo graphs exactly match because I divided the inputs by 10 in the call to foo. But that's not quite what I'm looking for as it makes the foo runtime look sublinear (only visually)